# How to recrawl pages with 4xx error code in scrapy while using cache?

Tags: scrapy

Is there a way to ignore 4xx error codes while recrawling a domain that is partialy within cache?

I have crawled a huge part of the page before running into issues, then I realigned the settings to not cache 4xx codes, because the crawler stoped

`Crawled (403) <GET https:/... ['cached']:`

Changed cache setting to: `HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = [401, 403, 404]`

This unfortunatelly seems to force me to recrawl the page without cache, as I am getting now this info from logs:

> INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www...>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed.

Either way, the crawler stops at the same position as it is retrieving the cached 403 response codes, while they are now 200 from non cache.

How can I adapt the settings in order to continue crawling the page?

Or as an alterantive, how can the cache be emptied/saved? Because otherwise I would need to override without the cache setting as far as I understand the docs.

Comment: if you specified `HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES` with `403` inside, then that's the actual response from the server, you are most likely being banned by the target site because of too many or incorrect requests.

Comment: You might be right, looks like it is comming from the server. Surprisingly I can call the site from the browser.

Comment: then you are doing the request incorrectly, I could help you a little if you share the site and what request you are doing

Comment: The requests should be OK as they worked before and work on other sites. Also the request works from scrapy shell. My crawler stopps exactly at the same amount of items scraped: 53302 with reason "finished". Most of the 403 carry "cached". I have set the crawler now to 3 URLs with 403 as starting URLs, With cash it stops almost imediatelly due to 403. Disabling the cache, will start crawling the page and the previous 403 pages will get a 200.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is to change the name of the crawler and start crawling fresh. This worked as it is using a new cache folder, but my original question was not answered by this and I had to recrawl pages I already had downloaded to cache.

Answer (score 0):

When you cache a page, then on each same request, scrapy goes to that cached data and if that page happened to be cached as 403 or any other, scrapy does not offer to crawl again. so, either you remove that page from the cached data or turn off cache to fetch the web page again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-ignore-http-codes) setting.